# Is there a Linux `setfacl --test` equivalent for BSD?

Tags: linux, freebsd, acl

[The Linux version of `setfacl`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html), as opposed to the [BSD version](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?format=html&query=setfacl(1)) has that very handy `--test` option:

```
   --test
       Test mode. Instead of changing the ACLs of any files, the resulting
       ACLs are listed.
```

Although I know `setfacl` is idempotent, it's very useful to test if `setfacl` must be run before actually running it (to nicely inform a user in a program, for example).

Is there a known way to do something similar using the BSD version of `setfacl`?

A way to do so would be to run `getfacl` and then compare the output with the arguments given to `setfacl` but it seems pretty tedious/messy as there are a lot of non-exclusive cases: default entries (`-d`), modify (`-m`) or remove (`-x`) entries, entries with capital-x `X` execute permissions, ... Definitely more hacking around and a more error-prone solution than the simple `--test`.
I'll have to default to that if nothing else is possible (scripting in Python), but I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing a simpler or already existing solution.

Comment: It would be noise to add it to the question, but the context behind this is to re-add BSD support to [the test part of the Ansible's `acl` module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/630e8ef9a6bb65cad1386be98e9c6825448fb7e7/files/acl.py#L193) that was lost during [this change](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/150).